# Creating By Categories pages with objects with 2 or more categories

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm am building a by type page for a pokedex ionic app. Most pokemon have 2 types and so they are stored in an array called "Types". I'm assuming that i need to loop through the array of types in the pokemon json data. I'm not sure how or where I should loop through it

Pokemon Json data

```
  [
  "Number": "001",
  "Name": "Bulbasaur",
  "Generation": "Generation I",         
  "Types": [
    "Grass",
    "Poison"
           ]
  ]
```

If I change the format of the Types array to match that of the Types Json data then it works fine but I lose the other type.

Type Json data

```
[
 {
   "Types": "Grass",

 },
 {
   "Types": "Poison",

 },
]
```

ByCategory Service

```
 getPokemonByCategory(Types: string[]): Observable<IPokemon[]> {

    console.log("getPokemonByCategory Service Called")

    return this.getAllPokemon()
        .map((pokemon: IPokemon[]) => pokemon.filter(p => p.Types === Types))
        .do(data => console.log("data object returned from http.get call:"))
        .do(data => console.dir(data))
        //.do(data => console.table(data))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

ByType component

```
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';



import { pokemonService } from '../../services/pokemon.service';
import { IPokemon } from '../../services/pokemon'
import { pokemonDetails } from '../pokemonDetails/pokemonDetails'

@Component({
    selector: 'page-ByType',
    templateUrl: 'ByType.html',
})
export class pokemonByType implements OnInit {
errorMessage: string;
pokemon: IPokemon[];
pokemonType: any;


constructor(private _pokemonService: pokemonService,
    private nav: NavController,
    private navParams: NavParams) {

}

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("ngOnInit function called! By Category");

    this.pokemonType = this.navParams.data;
    console.log("Nav" + this.navParams.data)

    this._pokemonService
        .getPokemonByCategory(this.pokemonType.Types)
        .subscribe(
        data => this.extractData(data),
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
    );
}

private extractData(data: any) {

    console.log("extractData function called!");
    console.log("data:")
    console.dir(data);

    this.pokemon = data;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through all the types of the pokemon, and check if the index of the pokemon within the types array is not -1.

Example:

```
return this.getAllPokemon()
.map((pokemon: IPokemon[]) => pokemon.filter((p) => {
    p.Types.forEach((type) => {
        return type === type;
    });
}))
.do(data => console.log("data object returned from http.get call:"))
.do(data => console.dir(data))
//.do(data => console.table(data))
.catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: I'm still getting an getting Array(0) from the console.dir(data)